"Environment multicol undefined" but it is defined
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}


\newenvironment{flagsAndExplanation}[2]
{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textit{#1} %commandFlags
        \begin{itemize}
            \item #2 %commandDescription
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
}

\newenvironment{commandTemplate}[3]
{
    \chapter{#1} %commandName
    \section{#2} %sectionName
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicol}{3}

\newcommand{\mainSomething}{GNU}
\newcommand{\derivedPackage}{coreutils}
\newcommand{\commandName}{ls}
\newcommand{\sectionName}{FilesFilter}

\begin{commandTemplate}{\mainSomething}{\derivedPackage}{\commandName}
\end{commandTemplate}

\newcommand{\commandFlags}{{\texttt{-a, --all}}}
\newcommand{\commandDescription}
{
    do not ignore file names that start with '.' .
}

\begin{flagsAndExplanation}{\commandFlags}{\commandDescription}
\end{flagsAndExplanation}

\renewcommand{\commandFlags}{{\texttt{
-d, --directory /
}}}
\renewcommand{\commandDescription}
{
    List just the names of directories in current 
}

\begin{flagsAndExplanation}{\commandFlags}{\commandDescription}
\end{flagsAndExplanation}

\end{multicol}
\end{document}

Is there something I have done wrong? Why does it work with a simple document, but not on mine?

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please make your sample code as minimal as possible while still exhibiting the problem behavior you wish to fix. A suggestion: For the sake of this example, the preamble need only contain a suitable \documentclass directive and the instruction \usepackage{multicol}. And the body of the document could be simplified to \begin{document} \begin{multicol}{3} bla bla bla \end{multicol} \end{document}. Everything else is fluff.

Note that your \newenvironments are working because of sheer luck. They expect two  mandatory arguments, the second one being presently grabbed as \par because of the empty lines you are leaving in the code.

\begin{multicol}

\end{multicol}

are the mistakes. It should be
\begin{multicols}

\end{multicols}

with the final "s".
